# Call with another caller ID

Tags: caller-id

Dear Android enthusiasts,

I have a landline telephone with expensive calling rates, while the contract in my android smartphone is quite cheap. In order to save money I would like to call with my handy, but showing the telephone number **of my landline**.
In that way people can call me back and I avoid revealing my smartphone number.

Do you have any idea, how to show another telephone number when calling? I know how to hide the number, but that is no solution.
Thanks!

Comment: That's called Caller ID spoofing and might not be  legal in your region. Anyhow, some SIP services coupled with relevant softwares, such as Linphone, let you do that. You can search in this direction.

Comment: @Firelord thanks, I'll take a look at *Linphone*. By the way, If there is such a law against spoofing is for evil people, I do not feel any guilt by showing my landline number instead of my mobile phone :)

Comment: how about just suppressing your mobile no

Comment: @alecxs The problem is then twofold: people may not answer, as they do not know who is calling. Moreover, if they cannot answer and they try to call back later, they have no number to do it.